# CUDA compiler infinite loop

Tags: c++, cuda

I am working on some test fixtures for CUDA code (that I didn't write). I stumbled into an issue with `std::vector<std::array<std::tuple<int, float>, N>>` causing an infinite loop in the compiler, until memory is exhausted.

The same code, compiled with gcc, compiles fine. Also, if I make the outermost container also be `std::array`, the code compiles. Does this make sense to anyone?

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

class Fixture
{
protected:
    static constexpr unsigned int num_peaks = 16;

    using Peak   = std::tuple<int, float>;
    using Raster = std::array<Peak, num_peaks>;
    using Truth  = std::vector<Raster>;     // this hangs (see below)
    // using Truth  = std::array<Raster,1>; // this compiles fine

    virtual auto getNews(bool the_truth = false) const -> Truth = 0;

    auto blowUp() -> void { auto theNews = getNews(); } // this causes the problem; remove and it works
};
```

CUDA 12.1 (nvidia/cuda:12.1.0-devel-ubi9 image)
gcc 12.1.1 (gcc-toolset-12-gcc-c++ package)

### Edit

Adding my Dockerfile, since it appears to be configuration-sensitive:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.1.0-devel-ubi9
RUN echo "install git"          \
 && yum update -y               \
 && yum install -y              \
        git                     \
        scl-utils               \
        gcc-toolset-12-gcc-c++  \
        gcc-toolset-12-gdb      \
        boost-devel             \
 && yum clean all && date

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/scl", "enable", "gcc-toolset-12", "--" ]
```

And the compiler command generated by CMake:

```bash
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler \
  -I/usr/src/project/PUBLIC \
  -I/usr/src/project \
  -I/usr/src/project/include \
  -I"/usr/src/project/build-DEBUG/core/unit" \
  -isystem "/usr/src/project/build-DEBUG/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include" \
  -isystem "/usr/src/project/build-DEBUG/_deps/googletest-src/googletest" \
  -g -std=c++20 \
  --generate-code=arch=compute_80,code=[compute_80,sm_80] \
  -Xcompiler=-fPIE \
  --compiler-options=-fdiagnostics-color=never \
  -MD -MT core/unit/CMakeFiles/coreUnitTest.dir/Bug.cu.o \
  -MF CMakeFiles/coreUnitTest.dir/Bug.cu.o.d \
  -x cu \
  -rdc=true \
  -c /usr/src/project/core/unit/Bug.cu \
  -o CMakeFiles/coreUnitTest.dir/Bug.cu.o
```

Comment: probably best to [file a bug](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911).  FWIW, your posted code, compiled with `nvcc -c` on CUDA 12.1 with gcc 10.2.1 compiles quickly and cleanly for me, so I'm unable to see the issue in that setup.  I also don't see any issues in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4of8E9TE5)

Comment: I hit submit again, and it went. Who knows? https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia_bug/4077236 ... suffers from lack of markdown support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NVIDIA confirmed:

1. The bug is reproducible
2. It is unique to GCC 12

Thanks, [Robert Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695960/robert-crovella) for pointing me in the right direction.